# Entity Framework EF4 complex types

Tags: entity-framework-4, complextype

How in EF4 can I make an imported function return a complex type, which is not generated by the designer?

So I have a custom class somewhere in my project and I want the stored proc result to be return as this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each class returned from EF must be "part" of designer and underlaying mapping. If you define class somewhere in your project without modeling in EDMX, EF will not know how to materialize object when function is executed.